# Show that the equation $x^2\equiv a \pmod n$ is solvable $\iff$ $a^{\phi (n)\over 2}\equiv 1\pmod n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n> 2$ be an integer such that $(\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})^*$ has a primitive root. Show that the equation $x^2\equiv a \pmod n$ is solvable $\iff$ $a^{\phi (n)\over 2}\equiv 1\pmod n$. I thought I should use Euler theorem, but it uses a prime number and I can't seem to relate $\phi(n)\over 2$ to $p-1\over 2$. I could really use your help.

Comment: You should use \pmod instead of \mod, it formats better

Comment: The Euler theorem isn't limited to prime numbers. It works for any number $n$.

Comment: [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) holds for $n = p$ prime. Euler's theorem tells you that for any fixed positive integer $n$ you have $a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ for every integer $a$ coprime to $n$. Since $\varphi(p) = p-1$ for $p$ prime, this is a generalisation of Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $a \in (\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})^*$ also, if $x^2\equiv a$, $x \in (\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})^*$, and the Euler theorem tells us that $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1$ and $x^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1$.

Direction "$\Rightarrow$":

$$a^{\frac{\phi(n)}{2}} \equiv (x^2)^\frac{\phi(n)}{2}  \equiv x^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1$$

Direction "$\Leftarrow$":

Since there is a primitive root $g$, you have that $a \equiv g^t$ for some $t\in \Bbb{Z}$. Now since $a^\frac{\phi(n)}{2} \equiv 1$, you must have that $t$ is even ($1\equiv a^\frac{\phi(n)}{2} = g^{t\frac{\phi(n)}{2}}$, so $\phi(n)$ divides ${t\frac{\phi(n)}{2}}$ i.e $\frac{t}{2}$ is an integer.)
Now pick $x = g^{\frac{t}{2}}$. This is a solution since
$$x^2 \equiv g^t \equiv a.$$

Comment: I didn't understand why $(x^2)^\frac{\phi(n)}{2}  \equiv a^{\phi(n)}$... How is it derived?

Comment: Use a rule of powers: $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$

Comment: I did, and got $(x^2)^{\phi(n)\over 2}\equiv x^{\phi(n)}$. I don't understand, however, how it becomes $a$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it should be $x$ instead of $a$. You have $x\not\equiv 0$, since $x^2 = a$. I'll edit.

Comment: So is $x$ coprime to n?

Comment: Thank you. You've helped me a lot.

Comment: You mean $\,\phi(n)\,$ divides $\,t\phi(n)/2,\,$ not reversely (as written).

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Let $\,g\,$ be a primitive root of order $\,2m = \phi(n),\,$ and $\,a = g^k.\,$ Then

$\exists x\!:\ g^{2x}\! = g^k\!\iff \exists x\!:\ 2x\equiv k\pmod{\!2m}\color{}{\iff} 2\mid k\iff 2m\mid km\iff g^{km} =1 $